# How to use subquery in caes statement

Tags: sql, select, subquery, case

I want use select~~~~ subquery in case statement
but I Don't know how to do this

In my idea is

CASE When 
(select ...from ... where .. )IS null
then ...
else ...
end as ...

but it's not working

Comment: try using exists instead of when XXXX is null

Comment: You need to be more specific about you want to do.  Also, I am guessing that you are referring to a `CASE` *expression*, which would often be preceded by `SELECT`.

Comment: The thing i want to do is

Comment: check  the result of subquery( basic query) then do otherthing

Comment: You can provide some sample data and desired result to help us understand what you really want to do.

Comment: here is sample code for undertstanding                the thing i want to do is      remove the =NVL

Comment: SELECT
            NVL(
            
            (SELECT REPLACE(WM_CONCAT(COMPANY_NAME),',','|')
                    FROM TABLE_K
                    WHERE SYS_ID = 'comp_id'
                        AND GRP_CD = 'comp_grp_cd'
                        AND STS != 'Status'
                        AND LANG_CD = 'eng'),
                        
                        
                        'X') AS TempString
        FROM DUAL

Answer (score 0):

You can do a temp table and query that

```
with
test as (select names from table where names=smith ) ---You can add in left 
--joins here or whatever - again not sure what you are trying to accomplish
select Case when name=smith then "Yes" else Null end as Case_test
from test
```

Probably an easier way to do it with a subquery but off the top of my head I'm not sure. We would need more detail on what you were trying to accomplish but this would probably do the trick.

Comment: I can't use with statement also because DB is Sybase

Comment: It should still work if you are using tsql to query the database